# Laravel - Retrieve pivot relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a following database schema:

```
users
    id

skills
    id

skill_user
    id
    user_id
    skill_id

endorsements
    id
    skill_user_id
```

The Laravel models are defined as following:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Skill')
            ->using(SkillUser::class)
            ->withPivot('endorsements_count')
            ->orderBy('endorsements_count', 'desc');
    }

}

class Skill extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->using(SkillUser::class)
            ->withPivot('user_id');
    }
}

class SkillUser extends Pivot
{
    public function endorsements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Endorsement', 'skill_user_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Endorsement extends Model
{
    public function skill_user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SkillUser');
    }
}
```

From the above, you can see that the `user` can have multiple `skills` joined through a many-to-many table called `SkillUser`. Further, each user's skill can be endorsed by other users (`endorsement`). The `endorsements` are joined on the pivot table (each user_skill can have multiple endorsements).

Now I am trying to figure out how to construct a query in Laravel (Eloquent) that will fetch a users with all his skills and for each skill, all it's endorsements in a SINGLE query.

When I do following:

```
User::with('skills')->findOrFail(1)->skills[0]->pivot->endorsements
```

It correctly returns the user and the skill information, but the endorsements inside of the pivot (UserSkill) are empty. Also when I inspect the pivot->relations, it is also empty.

On the other hand, if I query like this:

```
SkillUser::where('id', '=', 1)->first()->endorsements
```

I get all the endorsements correctly so I guess the relationship is set-up correctly. I think I am missing to somehow include the 'endorsements' specifically in the pivot table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to be sure; is that a "similar" response that you want? https://prnt.sc/se54b6

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Skill extends Model
{
    public function endorsements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Endorsement::class, 'skill_user_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Endorsement extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id')->select(['id', 'firstname', 'lastname']);
    }
}
```

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class)->using(SkillUser::class)->select(['skill_user.id']);
    }
}
```

I added `endorser` column to `endorsements` table to associate with user.

```
return User::with('skills.endorsements.user')->findOrFail(1, ['id', 'name']);
```

it prints something like this;

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "my-user",
  "skills": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "askill",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "skill_id": 1
      },
      "endorsements": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "skill_user_id": 1,
          "endorser": 2,
          "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "user-2"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "skill_user_id": 1,
          "endorser": 3,
          "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "user-3"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "bskill",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "skill_id": 2
      },
      "endorsements": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "skill_user_id": 2,
          "endorser": 2,
          "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "user-2"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "dskill",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "skill_id": 4
      },
      "endorsements": []
    }
  ]
}
```

here are the queries executed behind the scenes;

```
SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM `users`
WHERE `users`.`id` = '1'
LIMIT 1;

SELECT `skills`.*, `skill_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `skill_user`.`skill_id` as `pivot_skill_id`
FROM `skills`
         inner join `skill_user` on `skills`.`id` = `skill_user`.`skill_id`
WHERE `skill_user`.`user_id` in ('1');

SELECT *
FROM `endorsements`
WHERE `endorsements`.`skill_user_id` in ('1', '2', '4');

SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM `users`
WHERE `users`.`id` in ('2', '3');
```

Comment: Are you sure this will correctly join the tables - $this->hasMany(Endorsement::class, 'skill_user_id'); ? I mean is it some Laravel convention that it will know it needs to join on the SkillUser table even though it is done from the Skill model?

Comment: @Adam i appended executed queries behind the scenes to the answer.

Comment: I finally got into testing it and it does not seem to work. There are missing endorsements for most of the skills. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Adam i tested it via using sample data. https://prnt.sc/se6ecw as you may see from here; `skill_user` table is used between `users` and `skills` - `endorsements` is used between `skill_user`  and `user` table.

Comment: I made a db dump with some test data: https://textuploader.com/1c4kw If you look for example at skill_user table, record with ID 7, it should have one endorsement with id 118 - from user (endorser) with id 1. This endorsement is not returned by your solution. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @Adam you are right, i found the problem. There is a problem on `User` class - `skills` method. I am updating this method - and `Endorsement` class's `user` method for relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213562/discussion-between-ersoy-and-adam).